# Create an HTML form with one field and button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new in coding , there is a question that someone gave me and I can't find the right answer , this is the question :

Create an HTML form with one field and button.On button click,get the input,and return the sum of the previous value and the current input value.The value is 0 and input is 5->output is 5,then value is 5,input is 6-> output is 11 and etc.

I tried few things nothing even close , 
if someone can give me the answer Ill be much appreciated , thanks.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
Input: <input type="number" />
<br>
<input type="submit" value="To Sum"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: You're new to stackoverflow but please put your code in your question

Comment: Also you tagged JavaScript and jquery have you tried using either one of those. Your problem with your code is that 1 it does not sum up your variable and 2 also no spaces are allowed in variables so To Sum is not valid.

Comment: but its after i deleted few tries , I just don't know how to make a function in the html form , I mean like make the increase of the value you put and the new value...(im new to html,java script , i watched tutorials but nothing about how to do it...

Comment: You can't write in in your html it has to be in your JavaScript

Comment: yah I got it , my mistake was that I tried all in the html , now I understand that there is javascript code that not include in the html , thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There you go, but you should try doing it yourself. it's pretty easy to google things like "on button click" etc.

```js
var total = 0;

$('.js_send').click(function(){
  total += parseInt($('.number').val());
 $('.total').html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="0" class="number"/>
<input type="button" value="send" class="js_send"/>

<div class="total">0</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JQuery free version

```js
var oldInput = 0,
    newInput, 
    outPut;
    
document.querySelector("#showSum").onclick = function() {
    newInput = parseInt(document.querySelector("#newInput").value), 
    outPut = newInput + oldInput, 
    oldInput = outPut, 
    document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = outPut;
};
```

```css
#result {
    width: 275px;
    height: 21px;
    background: #ffb6c1;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="0" id="newInput">
<button id="showSum">Show Results</button>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to your problem. Put all below code into a html file and name it as index.html, then run the html page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>    
</head>
<body>
    Output : <label id="output">0</label>
    <form method="get" action="index.html">
        Your Input: <input type="text" id="TxtNum"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="lastvalue" name="lastvalue"  />
        <input type="submit" onclick="return doSum();" value="Sum" />
    </form>

    <script>
    //- get last value from querystring.

    var lastvalue = getParameterByName('lastvalue');        
    if (lastvalue != null) {
        document.getElementById("lastvalue").value = lastvalue;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = lastvalue;
    }

    /*
    * - function to calculate sum
    */
    function doSum() {
        var newvalue = 0;           
        if(document.getElementById("TxtNum").value != '')
            newvalue = document.getElementById("TxtNum").value;

        var lastvalue = 0;
        if(document.getElementById("lastvalue").value != '')
            lastvalue = document.getElementById("lastvalue").value;

        document.getElementById("lastvalue").value = parseInt(newvalue) + parseInt(lastvalue);
        output = parseInt(newvalue) + parseInt(lastvalue);
    }

    /*
    * - function to get querystring parameter by name
    */
    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
            results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in server side, You could have a static variable and update it on button click. More like

```
public static int prevValue;

public int buttonclick(.....){
int sum = textboxValue + prevValue;
prevValue = textboxValue;
return sum;
}
```

Comment: On the server side it depends on what language your server is written in

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sum=0;
    function summ()
    {
      localStorage.setItem("value",document.getElementById("text").value);
      var v=localStorage.getItem("value");
      sum=sum+parseInt(v);
      alert(sum);
    }
    </script>
    <html>
      <input id="text">
      <button id="submit" onclick="summ()">sum</button>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be pretty easy.
Created [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJLNXK) 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJLNXK

```js
function getResult(){
  var myinputValue=document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  var resultDiv=document.getElementById("result"); 
  if(myinputValue && !isNaN(myinputValue)){
  resultDiv.innerHTML=parseInt(myinputValue) + (resultDiv.innerHTML ? parseInt(resultDiv.innerHTML) : 0);
  } 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput">
<button id="btngetresult" onclick="getResult()">GetResult</button>
<p>
Result:   
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sum() {
var t1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value);
var t2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("pre").value);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = t1+t2;
document.getElementById("pre").value = t1;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form method="get" action="">
<input type="text" name="t1" id="t1">
<input type="button" value="get sum" name="but" onclick="sum()">
<input type="hidden" name="pre" id="pre" value="0">
</form>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```